# Control two DC brushed motors with two wires in common

Tags: motor, dc-motor, driver, full-bridge

I'm working on a retrofitting project. I need to control 3 DC brushed motors with full H-bridge drivers. In most scenarios the 3 motors have independent connections:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftUEuk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But in few cases the actual connections are the followings:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqOEoS.png)</sup>

The X motor has independent connections for both wires, while motors Y and Z have two wires in common.

**I cannot change the wirings** but I can modify the driver circuits. Of course, I'm trying to avoid to make a completely different driver just for few systems.

The circuit for each axis is this one:

[image: Full-Bridge driver]

If I connect the motors to the control board, Y and Z axis move together due to the shared wire.
I guess the original board (that I don't have, by the way) uses a dual power supply: the common wire goes to GND and a positive or negative voltage is applied to the other side of the motor.

**Do you see any solution to fit two full-bridge drivers like the ones above to this wiring?**

Comment: Presumably only one of the commoned motors is in use at a time, so you could use a relay to swap between them.

Comment: You may be able to program 3 half-bridges (as used to control a BLDC motor) to do what you want. But you haven't told us what that is ... on/off, variable speed with PWM, etc. Controlling Y and Z in opposite directions at full speed will not be possible.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I need to control the bridges with variable speed PWM 0..99%. I can live with Y-Z axis that move one at time. Due to my driver configuration I guess it's not possible to avoid an external switch like a relay, is it?

Comment: I mean, because no matter the levels on IN1 and IN2, two MOSFETs are always on, I cannot "disconnect" one motor switching off all the MOSFETs. If I could, I would not need the relay.

Comment: Just turn both MOSFETs off on one of the half bridges; teh other two control the other motor. At a wild guess, that's what the DT/SD pin on the driver is for.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, you're right. At the moment the `DT/DS` pin is shared across all the drivers. I'm going to split it so I can easily turn off only the desired one.